# GWT - How to add a space in DockLayoutPanel

Tags: html, css, gwt, widget, docklayoutpanel

I want to add two widgets in south of DockLayoutPanel, so it'll be shown as this:

---

center panel

---

a space of 14px height

---

a widget of 29px height

---

My problem is: If I use `addSouth(widget, 29);` it has no space.
If I use `addSouth(widget, 43);` it also has no space, but the widget is now 43px height.
I thought to define the widget's margin as 14px, but it doesn't help me, because the widget's margin covers the center panel.
What should I do? I tried also to do twice addSouth, and it produce the most nicer result, but it also wasn't as expected, and I prefer using of only one addSouth.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to add widget in separate LayoutPanel and then add panel to dock panel. Inside LayoutPanel just specify space from top.

```
LayoutPanel panel = new LayoutPanel();
panel.add(widget);
panel.setWidgetLeftRight(widget, 0, Style.Unit.PX, 0, Style.Unit.PX);
panel.setWidgetTopBottom(widget, 14, Style.Unit.PX, 0, Style.Unit.PX);

dockPanel.addSouth(panel, 43);
```

Comment: I'll try it, But... Isn't there a normal way to do it?

Comment: You can do it by playing a little bit with CSS. Panels in GWT do not cover everything and you need to combine them to reach the required result.

Answer (score 0):

to set the distance between widgets in a `DockPanel` use

`dockPanel.setSpacing(14);`

if you want the spacing only for a certain widget you have to use CSS or add a higher CellHeight to the dockPanel widget.

`dockPanel.setCellHeight(widget1, //widget1.heigth+14px);`

to place the widget at the bottom of the cell
`dockPanel.setCellVerticalAlignment(widget1, HasVerticalAlignment.ALIGN_BOTTOM);`
  
   

CSS:

```
.gwt-Label-foo {
    margin-top: 14px;
}
```

then add the dependentStyle to your widget(in this case a `Label`)
`widget.addStyleDependentName("foo");`

for help look here: [Add a StyleDependetName](http://www.gwtproject.org/doc/latest/tutorial/style.html#dependent) and here: [CSS Styling of Widgets](http://www.gwtproject.org/doc/latest/DevGuideUiCss.html)